# 1->2->3 activities, at third "back button" I want to go to the first one

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a MainActivity, then I call SecondActivity (where I choose a file whose data is given to ThirdActivity.

If back button is pushed, I want the app to go back yo MainActivity and not SecondActivity.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to do it.

1. In SecondActivity, call finish() immediately after you start Activity 3.
2. Pass in the NO_HISTORY flag in the Intent for SecondActivity when starting it in MainActivity.

Answer (score 1):

Just after you call startActivity with the Intent for activity 3, call finish in activity 2:

```
//in activity 2

    Intent intent = new Intent(...);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also override `onKeyPressed()` (or whatever it's called) for the back button and startActivity().